# how to calculate all index value in array using PHP?

Tags: php

I want to plus all index value on an array in PHP

I retrieve data as below

```
$c = $loan->data->lists('principal');
var_dump($c);'

array (size=34)
  0 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  1 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  2 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  3 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  4 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  5 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  6 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  7 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  8 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  9 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  10 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  11 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  12 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  13 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  14 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  15 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  16 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  17 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  18 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  19 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  20 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  21 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  22 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  23 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  24 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  25 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  26 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  27 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  28 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  29 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  30 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  31 => string '1600.0000' (length=9)
  32 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
  33 => string '0.0000' (length=6)
```

Comment: why not array_sum() ?

Comment: Show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this it work for me

```
 $c = $loan->payment->lists('paid_principal');
 $all = array_reduce($c, function($a, $b) { return $a + $b;  },0);
 dd($all);
```

But **array_sum** is better way

Comment: array_reduce($c, 'sum',0); will return null

Answer (score 2):

Use like this

```
<?php
$a=array("1"=>"test","5"=>"test2","8"=>"test3");
$num=array_keys($a);
echo array_sum ( $num );
?>

Output : 14
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first parse your array values into floats with [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) and [`floatval`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.floatval.php) :

```
$myArray = array_map('floatval', $myArray);
```

And then perform an [`array_sum`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-sum.php) to get the total :

```
$sum = array_sum($myArray);
```